# Gspread, PythonAnywhere: "OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable" - Trying to Connect to Google Sheets

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, pythonanywhere, gspread

`scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('NFL Redraft-e021dc0d5969.json', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)`

This code is working well on my local machine, but it is failing on PythonAnywhere with `OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable`

Any idea how to resolve? It did work 1 out of 10 times I attempted to run it. I've tried both console and ipython. Gspread and Praw are up to date.

```html
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-148cc5cb6e1b> in <module>()
   1303 players, draft_pick_assignments, ordered_picks, positions = initialize_draft()
   1304 pick_string, round_up, pick_up = pick_up_next()
-> 1305 x, x, x, comments, messages = authenticate_google()
   1306 comments_replied_to = restore_from_sheets(comments)
   1307 messages_processed = restore_from_sheets(messages)
<ipython-input-1-148cc5cb6e1b> in authenticate_google()
     39     scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds']
     40     creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('NFL Redraft-e021dc0d5969.json', scope)
---> 41     client = gspread.authorize(creds)
     42 
     43     sht = client.open("Redraft Test")
/home/jj2807/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gspread/client.py in authorize(credentials)
    400     """
    401     client = Client(auth=credentials)
--> 402     client.login()
    403     return client
/home/jj2807/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gspread/client.py in login(self)
     59 
     60             http = httplib2.Http()
---> 61             self.auth.refresh(http)
     62 
     63         self.session.add_header('Authorization', "Bearer " + self.auth.access_token)

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py in refresh(self, http)
    558                   request.
    559         """
--> 560         self._refresh(http.request)
    561 
    562     def revoke(self, http):

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py in _refresh(self, http_request)
    763         """
    764         if not self.store:
--> 765             self._do_refresh_request(http_request)
    766         else:
    767             self.store.acquire_lock()

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/oauth2client/client.py in _do_refresh_request(self, http_request)
    795         logger.info('Refreshing access_token')
    796         resp, content = http_request(
--> 797             self.token_uri, method='POST', body=body, headers=headers)
    798         content = _helpers._from_bytes(content)
    799         if resp.status == http_client.OK:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in request(self, uri, method, body, headers, redirections, connection_type)
   1312                     content = b""
   1313                 else:
-> 1314                     (response, content) = self._request(conn, authority, uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   1315         except Exception as e:
   1316             if self.force_exception_to_status_code:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _request(self, conn, host, absolute_uri, request_uri, method, body, headers, redirections, cachekey)
   1062             auth.request(method, request_uri, headers, body)
   1063 
-> 1064         (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
   1065 
   1066         if auth:

/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py in _conn_request(self, conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
    985             try:
    986                 if conn.sock is None:
--> 987                     conn.connect()
    988                 conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
    989             except socket.timeout:

/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py in connect(self)
   1250             "Connect to a host on a given (SSL) port."
   1251 
-> 1252             super().connect()
   1253 
   1254             if self._tunnel_host:

/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py in connect(self)
    847         """Connect to the host and port specified in __init__."""
    848         self.sock = self._create_connection(
--> 849             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    850         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)
    851 

/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    709 
    710     if err is not None:
--> 711         raise err
    712     else:
    713         raise error("getaddrinfo returns an empty list")

/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    700             if source_address:
    701                 sock.bind(source_address)
--> 702             sock.connect(sa)
    703             return sock
    704
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using the older version of gspread that is pre-installed on PythonAnywhere and it does not recognise the proxy settings, so you can't connect out. Try using a newer version of gspread.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you will probably have to upgrade to a paid account to fix this problem. According to the Python Anywhere staff, free accounts go through a proxy in order to limit them to the API whitelist. Gspread will apparently try going through the proxy one time, and bypass it the next. This is from the staff on another thread:

"This happens even with the same code -- that is, the exact same code might work one day and then not the next. Unfortunately the only fix we're aware of is to switch to a paid account."

https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/11822/